# How do I convert my existing two Activities of Android Studio into two fragments so that I can make the Navigation Bar?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new in Android Studio and I've been mostly learning through experimenting so it would be really appreciated if you could explain all the steps please.

I already have an app complete which has two Activities which are connected to each other. I made this in an Empty Activity. Now I want to this to have an Navigation Bar, what do I do?

I tried making a new Navigation Bar Activity and tried to copy paste everything, it worked for the layout file with the xml file but I can't where I should be putting in my code? I searched up numerous posts to no avail. My original code had over 300 lines so I really can't write it all over again. Can someone please help me out?

I'm doing this app in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use just one main activity and convert the current activities to Fragments. So if you've not heard of Fragments see here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments&ved=2ahUKEwj7wpaxxJnvAhXCx4UKHf9tAqQQFnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw13OtAaEKbecXytTb4qLxel

Then you can place a navigation bar widget on the main activity, this can be configured to the amount of fragments you need.